# Magento API with Python (GET CREDIT MEMOS) problems?

Tags: python, magento

i have this code here:

```
client = magento.API(url, apiuser, apipass)
with magento.Order(url, apiuser, apipass) as order_api:
    order_increment_id = '200001071 '
    status = 'canceled'
    order = order_api.info(order_increment_id)
    print order['total_paid']

meo = client.credit_memo.list()
print meo'''
```

The order is taken, and the 'total_paid' is printed, but when it comes to the credit memo i cannot take the list. Any help? THanks

Comment: Does your problem get solved?

Comment: Did you use Magento 3.0 as an API?